# The question sort/filter buttons overlap the right sidebar at some screen sizes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

1. Click on one of your tags.
2. After SO will bring results for your tag, resize your browser window

[image: SO Page]

As you can see, the buttons overlap the right side bar.

Comment: @Stijn Well, thanks for editing, also before asking here, I was thinking maybe this is not a right place to ask/post such questions?

Comment: You are in the right place :) Meta is for discussions, feature requests and bug reports. Just try to pay attention to the tags you use, read their description if you're not sure about a tag.

Comment: @Stijn Yeap, I'm new for this side of stack (and this kind of questions), so please forgive my mistakes :).

Comment: So why haven't they fixed it yet? Because as of today I am still getting that very same error...

Comment: @marvinIsSacul because they had higher priority tickets to solve.

Comment: @rene Oh okay, guess we can only hope that this error is one of their priorities then...